# Why are my GitHub status checks stuck in an "Expected" state?

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have enabled branch protection rules for my main branch and checked the box that says, "Require status checks to pass before merging." These status checks are Azure DevOps YAML pipelines, all with near identical PR and Trigger configurations that look like:

```yaml
// item-api-ci
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - release/*
  paths:
    include:
      - src/API/Item

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - release/*
  paths:
    include:
      - cicd/pipelines/buying/item/item-api-ci.yaml
      - src/API/Item
      - src/API/Shared
```

or

```yaml
// userprofile-api-ci
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - release/*
  paths:
    include:
      - src/API/UserProfile

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - release/*
  paths:
    include:
      - cicd/pipelines/buying/userprofile/userprofile-api-ci.yaml
      - src/API/UserProfile
      - src/API/Shared
```

I opened a PR work I have only touched files inside `src/Deal/` however every single one of my CI pipelines are showing as a required status check even though they have not been triggered. On top of that, the pipeline hasn't actually been triggered, they are only showing up as the status check.

[Required GitHub Status Checks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9xIh.png)

Is there another way to unstuck this PR besides disabling "Require status checks to pass before merging"?

I have tried:

1. Closing/opening the pull request
2. Pushing empty commits like:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push --force-with-lease
```

3. Merging a PR into my branch
4. Completely removing `triggers:` and `pr:` from one of my pipelines like:

```yaml
trigger: none
pr: none
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a `pr` trigger with a subset of path, a pipeline is triggered only when updates are pushed to those paths. Since `src/Deal/` is not in the include path list, the pipelines are not triggered. See more info from [PR triggers in GitHub repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers).

Your pipelines are showing as required status check because you set the main branch to be a protected branch and enable status checks. The required status checks must pass before you can merge your branch into the protected branch. It has nothing to do with the path filter in your `pr`.

You can check if [skipping checks for individual commits](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/collaborating-on-repositories-with-code-quality-features/about-status-checks#skipping-and-requesting-checks-for-individual-commits) works for you. To skip checks for a commit, type your commit message and a short, meaningful description of your changes. After your commit description, before the closing quotation, add two empty lines followed by `skip-checks: true`:

```
$ git commit -m "Update README
>
>
skip-checks: true"
```